# Javascript. Как проверить строку на повторяющиеся буквы?

Tags: javascript

Нужна функция которая: принимает в качестве аргумента строку(допустим "супер разработчик"), проверяет в этой строке наличие повторяющихся букв и возвращает true если есть, либо false!
 Интересует алгоритм проверки на повтор букв, не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот скрипт проверяет сколько раз повторяется в "супер разработчик" буквы.
Возрашает true если повторяются и false если нет.

```js
  
function charCheck(str)
{
for(i=0; i < str.length; i++)
  {
   if (str.split(str[i]).length-1 > 1) 
   {
    return true;
   }  
  }
  return false;

} 
str= "супер разработчик";
console.log(charCheck(str));
console.log(charCheck("затмил"));
```

Comment: Это то понятно))Спасибо. Но вы меня не правильно поняли. Получаем неизвестный аргумент со строкой, в котором проверяем есть ли там повторяющиеся буквы или нет, если есть то true если нет то false

Comment: Сейчас доработаю

Comment: Доработал теперь то что надо

Comment: Теперь то что надо))!

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой путь: бежать в цикле и подсчитывать количество вхождений символа, как только символ встретится повторно - можно возвращать true

```js
function checkDup(s) {
  var map = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (map[s[i]]) return true;
    map[s[i]] = 1;
  }
  return false;
}
var str = "супер разработчик";

console.log(str, checkDup(str));
console.log('супер', checkDup('супер'));
```

Альтернативным решением может быть использованием [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Так как в нем хранятся только уникальные элементы, можно создать Set из строки и сравнить размер получившейся коллекции с размером исходной строки, если размеры отличаются - то дубликаты присутствуют

```js
function checkDup(s) {
  return new Set(s).size != s.length;
}
var str = "супер разработчик";

console.log(str, checkDup(str));
console.log('супер', checkDup('супер'));
```